# How to get the value after a particular string is found in a text file , using shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a text file and the contents of the file are as follows:

```
#SERVICE INFO:
 srv id         [8503]
 serv rqst id   xxxxxx               
 serv rqst len   [17]
 serv status     [C]

#SERVICE INFO:
 srv id         [8501]
 serv rqst id   xxxxxx  
 serv rqst len   [17]
 serv status     [C]


#SERVICE INFO:
 srv id         [8500]
 serv rqst id   xxxxxx  
 serv rqst len   [17]
 serv status     [C]
```

I want to read the srv id and find its corresponding status and use it for further validation.

For ex: 
for srv id 9500, serv status is C

I have tried the below awk statement:

```
awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I == "service id") {print $(I+1)};}' $testfile
```

It gives me a blank output.

Here testfile is my sample text file.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I can't tell if you want to output all id+status pairs, or want to lookup an id and print it's corresponding status or something else. Please [edit] your question to clarify and provide the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: Hello Ed, I want to lookup an id and print it's corresponding status

Comment: And yet you accepted an answer that does the other thing. OK....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F '[][]' '$1 ~ /srv id/ {id = $2} $1 ~ /serv status/ {print id, $2}' file
```

That uses `[` *or* `]` as the field separator. If the first field contains "srv id", remember the id. If the first field contains "serv status", print the id and the status value.

Output:

```
8503 C
8501 C
8500 C
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind Perl:

```
perl -00 -ne 'm{srv id.+?(\d+).+status.+\[(\w)\]}s and print "$1 $2\n"' file
```

This yields:

```
8503 C
8501 C
8500 C
```

The `-00` switch tells Perl to read the file in "paragraph mode" where a record separator is one or more blank lines.

We match a sequence of characters that begin with "srv id" and ends with the token "status" followed by its value.  A dot is any character; the `+` signifies one or more; and the `+?` denotes non-greedy matching. `\d` signifies a digit and `\w` a word character.  Opening and closing square brackets must be escaped to mean themselves. In order to have a dot match a newline character, we add the `s` modifier at the end of the match pattern `m{...}s`

Should you want to look up an ID to print its status, simply `grep` for the ID in the output, piped to `grep`:

```
perl ... | grep 8501
```